# How do I "import" an xml schema for xjb code generation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm new to using xml, and having trouble figuring this out. I found a schema for the RSS spec online, and I can generate java classes from that self-contained schema using `xjc` without issues.

I want to add fields from [`simpledc.xsd`](https://www.dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/simpledc.xsd) because in RSS feeds, I'm seeing tags like `dc:creator` on `<items>`, and I'd like to set it up so code generation for that can work too. In my attempt, I added the `xsd:include` for the `dc` schema, and added a field to the `item` definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- My addition -->
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="simpledc.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="rss" type="rss" />

    <xsd:complexType name="rss">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="channel" type="channel" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="1" />
...

    <xsd:complexType name="item">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        The title of the item.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            ...
            <!-- My addition -->
            <xsd:element name="creator" type="dc:creator" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Intellij provides the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'dc:creator'
```

And `xjc` also provides a similar error:

```
$ xjc -p com.test.generated -d src/main/java/ src/main/resources/schemas/rss.xsd
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'type' in element 'element'. Recorded reason: UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'dc:creator' as a QName: the prefix 'dc' is not declared.
  line 391 of file:/<project>/src/main/resources/schemas/rss.xsd
```

How do I set this up properly so that I can add elements with the `dc` namespace in my xml schema, and have codegen work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. I used an `include` where I should have used an `import` because I was referencing a different namespace. And then for the element from the different namespace, I need to use a `ref` to link to them:

```
<xsd:schema 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="dc.xsd" namespace="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/>
...
    <xsd:complexType name="item">
        <xsd:sequence>
            ...
            <!-- My addition -->
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="dc:creator" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

I'm not sure what the intent of the `simpledc.xsd` provided by the dublin core website. Using `dc.xsd` seems to work for generating the schema.

Unfortunately, when you're trying to unmarshall xml according to this schema, it seems that the rss feed author needs to add `xmlns` fields at the top level `<rss>` element, and they mostly do not.